# Toggle spellcheck globally

Tags: spell-checking

It is possible to `set nospell` in `.vimrc` to disable it globally. But it doesn't [override filetype plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169337/set-nospell-in-vimrc-has-no-effect).

Is it possible to toggle between `spell` and `nospell` globally so that I can at least disable it once for all open buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn spell on for all the open buffers I would do:

```
:bufdo set spell
```

And to turn spell off for all the open buffer I would do:

```
:bufdo set nospell
```

For some filetype the standard change the general `spell` settings.
You can override that by adding an `after` script.

e.g.: If you want to activate spell for the python filetype you could add:
`.vimfiles/after/ftplugin/python.vim`
with the following content:

```
setlocal spell
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to make use of a `VimEnter` autocommand in conjunction with an `OptionSet` autocommand, the reason being, that `OptionSet` is not triggered during startup and loading of runtime files during that time.

So the following may work:

```
augroup MyCustomGroup
au!
au VimEnter * ++once :set nospell
au OptionSet spell :setl nospell
```

If the VimEnter still triggers to early, you may have to fallback to a custom timer.